# python capture environment variables

Tags: python, linux, bash

this bash script can catch all the environment variables which are set when data is passed through STDIN eg such as:

```
echo "Hello" | ./script.sh
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

CAPTURE_FILE=/var/log/capture_data
env >> ${CAPTURE_FILE}
exit 1
```

it there any way i can do same in python??

**RESOLVED:**

this is the resultant python version..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

def capture():

    log = os.environ
    data = open("/tmp/capture.log", "a")
    for key in log.keys():
        data.write((key))
        data.write(" : ")
        for n in log[key]:
            data.write('%s' % ((n)))
        data.write("\n")
    data.close()
    sys.exit(1)

def main():

    capture()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, check out [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ).

```
matan@swarm ~ $ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jan 20 2012, 17:51:10) 
[GCC 4.6.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ
{'LOGNAME': 'matan', 'WINDOWID': '25165833', 'DM_CONTROL': '/var/run/xdmctl', 'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'SSH_AGENT_PID': '3648', 'LANG': 'en_GB.UTF-8', ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ) is a mapping that contains all environment variables and their values.